# Why my animation is not active?

Tags: css

hello i want to make my background move but the animation is not active. Why ?

```
@keyframes anima {
    0% {
        background-position-y: 0px;
    } 100% {
      background-position-y: -150px;
    }
}

#bando {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: url(neon.jpg);
    background-size: 130%;
    width: 600px;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    height:150px;
    animation-name: anima;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
```

Thanks in advance to help me because I am blocked on it since 4 hours

try this in https://jsfiddle.net/526vttyg/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `animation-duration`, and you have to specify that, otherwise the animation won't do anything. The default `animation-duration` is `0`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration

```css
#bando {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: url(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png);
  background-size: 130%;
  width: 600px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-name: anima;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes anima {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bando"></div>
```